# Remove first line in text file without allocating memory for entire text file

Tags: php, unix, text-files

I have a very large text file and all I need to do is remove one single line from the top of the file. Ideally, it would be done in PHP, but any unix command would work fine. I'm thinking I can just stream through the beginning of the file till I reach \n, but I'm not sure how I do that.

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed -i -e '1d' file` will do what you want.

- `-i` indicates "in-place"
- `-e` means "evaluate this expression"
- `'1d'` means, delete the first line

Comment: "delete" is expensive. why not just print from line 2 onwards.

Answer (score 6):

you can use a variety of tools in *nix. A  comparison of some of the different methods on a file with more than 1.5 million lines.

```
$ wc -l < file4
1700589

$ time sed -n '2,$p' file4 > /dev/null

real    0m2.538s
user    0m1.787s
sys     0m0.282s

$ time awk 'NR>1' file4 > /dev/null

real    0m2.174s
user    0m1.706s
sys     0m0.293s

$ time tail -n +2 file4 >/dev/null

real    0m0.264s
user    0m0.067s
sys     0m0.194s

$time  more +2 file4 > /dev/null

real    0m11.771s
user    0m11.131s
sys     0m0.225s

$ time perl -ne 'print if $. > 1' file4 >/dev/null

real    0m3.592s
user    0m3.259s
sys     0m0.321s
```

Comment: +1 for the timings of the various solutions, all of which work and are a lot more elegant than some of other suggestions here

Answer (score 1):

If your file is flat, you can use `sed '1d' file > newfile`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
sed -n '2,$p' file
```

Comment: and -i for replace original file content

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tail from GNU coreutils:

```
tail -n +2 file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n +2 < source > destination
```

Tail with positive number outputs everything starting with N-th line.

Comment: depends on system and version of tail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big is your file, but did you try `awk 'NR > 1' {print}` ?

Comment: awk is too big cannon for this job. If he wants to do this operation regulary (scripted), awk is not 'great' solution

Comment: @Martin, explain too big cannon. awk is one of the fastest file processing tool available in *nix. If you don't know anything, don't comment.

Comment: What's the difference between awk and sed in this respect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on perl, but this might do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$first = true;
while (<>)
{
    if ($first)
    {
        # skip first line
        $first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        print;
    }
}
```

and use this script as a filter:

```
cat myfile.txt | removefirstline.pl > myfile_2.txt
```

Comment: This is probably overkill considering it can be done with basic unix text manipulation tools ;).

Comment: its not overkill. Perl is just another tool to do the job.  >>
perl -ne 'print if $. > 1' file

Answer (score 0):

```
function cutline($filename,$line_no=-1) {

$strip_return=FALSE;

$data=file($filename);
$pipe=fopen($filename,'w');
$size=count($data);

if($line_no==-1) $skip=$size-1;
else $skip=$line_no-1;

for($line=0;$line<$size;$line++)
if($line!=$skip)
fputs($pipe,$data[$line]);
else
$strip_return=TRUE;

return $strip_return;
}

cutline('foo.txt',1); // deletes line 1 in foo.txt
}
```